# Permutations-with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

1. Let's say there is a password  consist of 5 characters (replacement are allowed) with lowercase and you forgot your password but remember it had 2h's and 2's and 1 A. would the probability of guessing your password on the first attempt be just (5P2*5P2*5P1)/26^5
2. let's say a class contained 5 boys and 5 girls. how many ways can I select a secretary? In this case both combination and permutation would be valid no? 10C1 or 10P1, the same wouldn't apply to 2 secretaries as the order here doesn't matter so it can be just 10C2?

Comment: "*would the probability be...*"  The probability of what?  You haven't described a question that has anything random happening in it.  The probability that someone who doesn't know anything about your password can correctly guess it if they know it was supposed to be 5 characters and nothing else?  The probability that you can guess your password correctly given you remember it is 5 characters and has 2 h's, two 2's, and an A?  The probability that someone randomly guessing a password not knowing you came up with a password that you weren't sure if it was yours or not based on memory?

Comment: As for your second question... the answer can be thought of even more simply as *just being 10*... There is no need to have involved C's or P's in any of your thought process here.

Comment: @JMoravitz the first question has been edited and 10 would just apply to the first part  of Q2. And for part two, the part about 2 secrecies it would be just 10C2 no ?

Comment: With the phrasing of the first question as it is now, the numerator should be $1$ and the denominator should be the number of passwords that were possible given what you remember about it.  The number of passwords possible will not involve "P's" at all... It will be a multinomial coefficient, or equivalently several binomial coefficients.  Pick where the $A$ was.  Then *from the remaining positions* pick where the $h$'s were.  It will be a rather small number.

Comment: I thought it would be just 5P5/26^5 for the first question

Comment: No.   26 doesn't appear at all in the correct answer. Only 5's and numbers smaller than 5

Comment: For Question 2 part two the one regarding 2 secretaries It would be a combination question as the role are same and the order doesn’t matter right ? I.e 10C2

Answer (score 1):

You remember that your password had two `h`'s, two `x`'s, and one `a` (*or whatever that middle letter was supposed to be which you have failed to actually write in your post*) and we are guessing one of the possible passwords **from those who also have** two `h`'s, two `x`'s, and one `a`...

Let's count how many of those types of passwords there are.  Well, we can start by choosing where the `h`'s go.  There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways we can place the `h`'s.  Then after the `h`'s are placed, let us choose where the `x`'s go.  There are $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways to continue to place the `x`'s and then only one way to place the `a` after that... for a total of $\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\color{grey}{\cdot 1} = 30$ different passwords possible which match what we vaguely remember about our actual password.

So... we are guessing one of these $30$ passwords.  We are **not** guessing one of the many other passwords who do not fit the pattern.  We are **not** guessing anything with the letter `z` for instance.  We are **not** caring about the number $26$ at all... every letter which we do not remember as being part of our password may as well not exist.  One of these $30$ passwords is the correct password.  Since we are guessing at random from these $30$ passwords our probability of guessing correctly is simply

$$\dfrac{1}{\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{30}$$

---

We could also have found the number $30$ a different more direct way using [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients), having described it as the multinomial coefficient $\binom{5}{2,2,1} = \frac{5!}{2!2!1!}=30$

Comment: That would be valid if replacements are not allowed however if replace are allowed it would be just 1/(5C2 x 5C2 x 1)

Comment: "*replacements are allowed*"  Replacements of **positions**?  What... we are allowed to replace positions within the password?  So we can have something like $h\!\!\!a~~~x\!\!\!h x$ as a possible password? where we have the $h$ and the $a$ overlapping both occupying the first position?  You really need to think before you speak.

Comment: No... in any standard interpretation of the word "passwords" only one letter can ever occupy a position in the string at a time.  There is only one letter in the first position in the password.  There is only one letter in the second position in the password and so on...

Comment: replacements of the letters

Comment: Read and follow along more closely... *we pick which two positions are used for h*.  Those two positions which are picked are then both used for the letters h.  The letter h is "repeated", sure.  "*Replaced*" doesn't really make sense as a word here in this context, we are not "*replacing*" anything.  What is being picked however are **positions** within the password.  We pick the **positions** used by the first and second h.  Once we have picked those positions (*which are most certainly not picked with replacement*) we move on to picking which positions are occupied by the x's and so on...

Comment: You are far too enthusiastically reaching for P's and C's and for formulas and are missing the forest for the trees.  You need to work on reading comprehension and the fundamental concepts at play here.

Comment: I am just saying what the question is stating  and in this case replacements just means repetitions are allowed

Comment: And you are not understanding in what way it is relevant.  I am telling you there are $30$ passwords that fit the description provided.  Yes, there are $26^5$ different length5 passwords that could have been made on the first day where you were asked to initially create a password, but we are not talking about that.  We are talking about months later when you already have a created password... and you remember that the password had two `h`'s, two `x`'s, and an `a`.  The "repeats are allowed in a password" is still being respected by the very fact that we know we have two h's in the password

Comment: That however does not change any of the calculations at this point (*and is not new information*) and we still have $30$ different passwords made up of two h's, two x's and an a.  Your insistence that "replacement" having appeared as a word somewhere in the problem implies that every time in which any calculation is performed we change the manner in which we calculate is flat out wrong.  You need to understand what it is we are counting.  You need to understand what it means to choose positions in a string.  You need to understand that once a position is chosen it cannot be chosen again.